# How to access files in Java ME

Tags: java-me, writefile

I want to access the files encircled in this screenshot.
What path should I use?

This is for my JavaME application. file:///ParseExample/service1.xml doesn't seem to be the right one.

http://www.fileden.com/files/2010/5/28/2872707//projectfiles.JPG

Edit:
Here is my code:
FileConnection fconn = (FileConnection) Connector.open("file:///ParseExample/service1.xml", Connector.READ_WRITE);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If these are files that you are going to be bundling in your MIDlet JAR then you need to use [Class.getResourceAsStream()](http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr118/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)).

Answer (score 0):

have you tried `new File("ParseExample/service1.xml");`?

This access the file with a relative path instead of a absolute path, as in your example. (You could also try `"file://ParseExample/service1.xml"`(only two slashes after the colon).

And, as funkybro said, if you are packing it in a jar, you need Class.getResourceAsStream()...